# How does vertical align works in css?

Tags: css

This property confuses me a lot.  please take a look at below snippet.

body:

```html
 <div class="parent">
       <img src="./cat.jpeg" width="100" height="100" class="img"></img>
       <div class="child child1">X</div>
       <div class="child child2">X</div>
       <span>X</span>
    </div>
```

style:

```html
<style>
        body,
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

      .parent {
        outline: 1px solid red;
        margin:  100px auto;
        margin-left: 100px;
      }

      .child {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }

      .child1 {
        outline: 1px solid green;
      }

      .child2 {
        outline: 1px solid orange;
      }
    </style>
```

If i set `.img { vertical-align: text-bottom; }` it will behave below, I guess the reason is the last X could be considered as the strut. The img baseline is its bottom so it matches the X descent area.
[image]

If i set `.img { vertical-align: bottom; }` it will show below, but why?
[image]

It looks like with different vertical align configuration, the parent line box baseline or linebox height is not static, could someone please give a detail explanation on this? thank you.

Comment: If you set `bottom`, then the bottom of the `<img>` will be set to the bottom of its `<div>` parent.  The size of the `<div>` is set by the size of the image, so no stretching is needed.

Comment: The CSS spec contains a section on [inline formatting contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting) which may be helpful.

Comment: It's possible the confusion is as much with what display: inline-block and span are doing as with vertical-align. Try putting several lines in the span for example.

Comment: `vertical-align` confuses pretty much everybody. I recommend reading [Vertical-Align: All You Need To Know (CSS)](https://christopheraue.net/design/vertical-align) - still the clearest explanation of how it works.

Comment: Thank you guys! I will read the posts shared. :  )

Answer (score 0):

> the parent line box baseline or linebox height is not static

You can check [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#line-height) for the full detail but the most important part is:

> The line box height is the distance between the uppermost box top and the lowermost box bottom.

So yes the height is not static and depends on the vertical alignment of each element. The browser will first align all the items correctly then the line box should be tall enough to contain all the of them.

Answer (score -2):

When the vertical-align value is `bottom` then it aligns the bottom of the element and its descendants with the bottom of the entire line. Since the elements are displayed as 'inline'(span and image) or 'inline-block'(div), the parent takes up the size of the tallest element.